# Access to a variable inside shiny r and reuse it

Tags: r, shiny

I have defined a global variable called  y_kmeans in clustering plot as following : and I want to use this variable later in a table:

Server.R

```
  output$plot4<-renderPlot({
        df<-rawdata()
        #clustering of Related IP address and the number of movie downloads and number of user_id
        df<- na.omit(df)
        df5 <-df[3:4]
        #%>% dplyr::select(user_id,pa_content_name)
        #set.seed(12)
        split <- sample.split(df5, SplitRatio = 0.85)
        training_set <- subset(df5, split == TRUE)
        test_set <- subset(df5, split == FALSE)
        # Feature Scaling
        training_set = scale(training_set)
        test_set = scale(test_set)
        # Using the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters
        # Fitting K-Means to the dataset
        set.seed(28)
        kmeans = kmeans(x = df5, centers = 3)
        y_kmeans <<- kmeans$cluster

      })
```

So To add this variable in a table I have used following codes:

```
#Demand of titles 
  GroupingVal <- reactive({
    df<-rawdata()
    #Grouping the Values based on clustering
    df$cluster<-kmeans$cluster
    df<-df %>% mutate(group=ifelse(cluster==1,"A",
                                   ifelse(cluster==2,"B",
                                          ifelse(cluster==3,"outlier","outlier"
                                          ))))
    df
  })
```

and the code related to renderDatatable is as follows:

```
 output$filteredtbl<-DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(GroupingVal)){return()}
        DT::datatable(GroupingVal(),extensions="Responsive",options=list(pageLength=3),class='cell-border strip',selection='single')
      })
```

The error that I received is 
"object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"
could you please let me know where is the problem.

Comment: You can compute all the data outside renderPlot() using a reactive({}). renderPlot() function can take the values out of the reactive({}) if you set up a list for such variables (in case there are many) or the last line should be the variable to export. Later at renderDataTable() you can take the values needed for the table.

Comment: Thanks It works pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way that you can get it:

```
k_means<-reactive({
    #clustering to find the groups of passionate IPS
    df<-rawdata()
    #clustering of Related IP address and the number of movie downloads and number of user_id
    df<- na.omit(df)
    df5 <-df[3:4]
    #%>% dplyr::select(user_id,pa_content_name)
    #set.seed(12)
    split <- sample.split(df5, SplitRatio = 0.85)
    training_set <- subset(df5, split == TRUE)
    test_set <- subset(df5, split == FALSE)
    # Feature Scaling
    training_set = scale(training_set)
    test_set = scale(test_set)
    # Using the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters
    # Fitting K-Means to the dataset
    set.seed(28)
    kmeans = kmeans(x = df5, centers = 3)
    y_kmeans <<- kmeans$cluster
    y_kmeans
  })
```

And then call the k_means() in the GroupingVal reactive function:

```
GroupingVal <- reactive({
    df<-rawdata()
    df$cluster<-k_means()
    df<-df %>% mutate(group=ifelse(cluster==1,"A",
                                   ifelse(cluster==2,"B",
                                          ifelse(cluster==3,"outlier","outlier"
                                          ))))
    df
  })
```

And then call it in renderDatatable:

```
output$filteredtbl<-DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(GroupingVal)){return()}
    DT::datatable(GroupingVal(),extensions="Responsive",options=list(pageLength=3),class='cell-border strip',selection='single')
  })
```